# Change sort order of sub categories in magento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I have some code that calls the sub categories of a main category and I need to be able to change the sort order of teh sub categories on the front end of the site.

I have tried adding the attribute to sort tag but this isnt doing anything. Can anyone help point me in the right direction to get this working. Many Thanks:

```
->addAttributeToSort(’position’, ‘asc’)
```

This is isnt having any affect on the order. The code i'm using is below:

```
          <?php 
        //get the current category
        $_cat = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
        $currentCat = $_cat->getCurrentCategory();

        //get the children of the current category
        $subCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getId())->getChildren();
        //get sub category ids
        $subCatIds = explode(',',$subCats);
        ?>
      <?php if (count($subCatIds) > 1): ?>
      <?php foreach($subCatIds as $subCatId): ?>
      <?php $subCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatId); ?>
      <?php if($subCat->getIsActive()): ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

@Jason Millward
Please do not call load() to every object. It will affect site performance in the nearest future ;) 
I created an example for you.

```
    $currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
    $collection = $currentCategory->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($currentCategory->getChildren())
        ->setOrder('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
        ->load();
```

category entity already have position attribute that is managed from admin.
Just use it to order categories.

Comment: thanks for this but where do I add this to the code to call this? Many Thanks

Comment: well, depends of the place you want it :)

Comment: can it be added to the code I already posted above or do I need to look at rewriting it to make this fit?

Comment: sure you can you it right there.
just replace first line:
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

you can write the code after $subCats

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $subCats))
              ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');
if($collection)
{
  $subCatIds = $collection->setOrder('position', 'asc');
}
```

after doing `foreach` $subCatIds you can go with the `id`. Hope this will help ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the sub categories of specific category with ordering by position. Please try this:

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection $storeCategories */
$storeCategories =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(
    $currentCategory->getId(), 0, false, true, false
);
$storeCategories->unshiftOrder('position',  Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC);
```

Notify that we must use **unshiftOrder** instead of **setOrder**. Otherwise, before loading the collection, it will be set ordering by name first.
I was reference to the top menu to see how it work. Hope this will help somebody!